# Generar un código automático en un campo Textfield

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Estoy creando un campo input textfield y me gustaria que en ese campo, en vez de ingresar un código manualmente, se genere automático de manera aleatoria.

Alguna idea ?

```js
<h3>Agregar nueva Reserva</h3>
      <br/>
        <TextField  color="secondary" variant="outlined" className={styles.inputMaterial} label="Código* " name="CODIGO" onChange={handleChange}/>          
        <br />
```

Según la sugerencia entregada agregue el código, y me muestra el código en el campo, pero ahora no me deja guardar.

Este es el nuevo código :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código Nuevo :

```js
 const texto = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
  let codigo = ''
  const longitud_codigo = 8
  
  for (let i = 0; i < longitud_codigo; i++) {
      codigo += texto.charAt((Math.random() * longitud_codigo));
  }


const bodyInsertar=(
    <div className={styles.modal}>
      <br/>
      <h3>Agregar nueva Reserva</h3>
      <br/>
        <TextField  defaultValue={codigo} color="secondary" variant="outlined" className={styles.inputMaterial} label="Código* " name="CODIGO" onChange={handleChange}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes generar un código aleatorio de tamaño "longitud_codigo" de esta forma:

```
const texto = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
let codigo = ''
const longitud_codigo = 8

for (let i = 0; i < longitud_codigo; i++) {
    codigo += texto.charAt((Math.random() * longitud_codigo));
}

console.log(codigo)
```

Básicamente luego cambias la propiedad del elemento TextField por ese "codigo"

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia, pero como se lo cambio?